# Lighttable, set font size

Tags: ide, lighttable

i am new on Lighttable IDE.
anyone know how to set `workspace` and windows font size.
i can change editor font size. but dont know how to set `font-size` for other element.
or change font-size global for all IDE fonts.

Comment: currently `ctrl -` reduces the font of some elements outside the editor, but `ctrl +` does nothing so you get stumped really fast....

Answer (score 26):

Open commands pane (`^Space`), search for "User behaviour". This will open config file. Add the following into the middle  (LightTable 0.7+):

```
[:editor :lt.objs.style/font-settings "Menlo" 13 2]
```

On older LightTable versions add this instead:

```
:editor [:lt.objs.editor/no-wrap
              (:lt.objs.style/font-settings "Menlo" 13 2) ;; font-family: Menlo, font-size: 13px, line-height: 2em
              (:lt.objs.style/set-theme "default")]
```

Comment: tnx . but i try it . it change editor font and not effect on workspace or other element like windows name font or files font-size

Comment: @ash (via [suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6282913)): You probably should submit that as a separate answer; modifying an existing answer to add new methods is not recommended unless the answer is a community wiki.

Answer (score 4):

- Press CTRL Space and search "user behaviors"

*Click on Settings: User behaviors

*Uncomment (remove ;;) under  ;; Common behaviors to consider the following line
  ;;[:app :lt.objs.style/font-settings "Arial" "13"] and change the last value which represents the font size

[image]

Answer (score 1):

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/light-table-discussion/KJpBfOPy660
`zoom` for alternative option..

Answer (score 0):

Put following line in `user.behaviors`:

```
[:app :lt.objs.plugins/load-css "/home/&lt;your_username>/.config/LightTable/console.css"]
```

In `console.css` put something like this:

```
ul.console, em.file, em.line {
    font-family:"DejaVu Sans"
    font-size:12px;
}

ul.console > li > table > tr > td > pre {
    font-family:"Ubuntu Mono";
    font-size:12px;
}
```

Of course, you need not have two different font families as filename and output are already printed in different colors, but there it is.

CSS styling is not dynamically reloaded as user keybindings and behaviors, if you change your CSS, you need to close & reopen LightTable. That should be fixed, hopefully someone will open an issue at github issue tracker. ;)