# Increase size of console window in LightTable (Juno)

Tags: css, julia, lighttable

I'd like to increase the size of the console window in LightTable (I'm using the Juno plugin for Julia).

I've searched around for a relevant command for the User-behaviour file but haven't found anything. Perhaps I need to edit the theme/skin css file? If so, any pointers as to what field I should be editing?

*Note 1*: I've tried looking through the Ctrl+Space menu but didn't find anything there.

*Note 2*: I'm aware I can get the console window full screen as a separate tab. This is not what I'm after.

*Note 3*: Since at least one commenter has misinterpreted the question, I thought I should emphasize here that I'm not trying to change font settings. It is the size of the console window itself, ie the bit that gets printed to using something like `println("I get displayed in the console")` that I am trying to increase.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25534216/lighttable-set-font-size
Looks like the first number is the font size and the second the line spread. I love Ubuntu Mono and I'm giving a talk, so I now use
`[:editor :lt.objs.style/font-settings "Ubuntu Mono" 18 1]`

Comment: @Wauzl Thanks for the comment. The command you refer to is used to alter the font, font-size, and line-spacing in the LightTable editor. I'm actually after the command to increase the size of the window itself that is allocated to the console (the bit that usually sits below the editor for most themes/skins). Sorry, I'll try and edit the question to make this a little more obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood you correctly, you do that with just your mouse.  There's kind of a dead-zone between where the code editor stops and the console output starts.  If you slowly move your cursor through that deadzone going towards the bottom of the screen, it will change and allow you to click-and-drag to resize the console.  The bar to click on is basically hidden, so I understand the confusion.

I couldn't get my mouse to be captured correctly in the screenshot, but it's approximately where the cursor seems to be in my attached screenshot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGlYu.png

Comment: Found it!!! I've been using LightTable for 3 months now and have never noticed my cursor switch as I hover over that "dead-zone". Very subtle. Many thanks.

Comment: @ColinTBowers another option is to load the console in a tab-set and control it's horizontal width but have the pleasure of a more 'full' window. I have the command to do so bound to pmeta-K.